# Insert Update таблицы

Tags: oracle

Есть две таблицы. Нужно сделать `Insert`, `Update` в таблице `R.USER` с таблицы `M.TEMP_USER`.

Написал такой скрипт:

```
SELECT * FROM M.TEMP_USER;
SELECT * FROM R.USER;

MERGE INTO R.USER A
USING (SELECT PARID , HR , TYPE_ID , ACTIVE FROM M.TEMP_USER) B
ON (A.PARID = B.PARID AND A.TYPE_ID = B.TYPE_ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET A.PARID = B.PARID,
             A.HR = B.HR ,
             A.TYPE_ID = B.TYPE_ID 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(A.PARID , A.HR, A.TYPE_ID , A.ACTIVE)
  VALUES(B.PARID , B.HR, B.TYPE_ID , B.ACTIVE )
```

, но выдает ошибку:

> COLUMNS REFERENCED IN THE ON CLAUSE CANNOT BE UPDATE "PARID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
MERGE INTO T_USER A
USING TEMP_USER B
ON (A.PARID = B.PARID AND A.TYPE_ID = B.TYPE_ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET  A.HR = B.HR
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(A.PARID , A.HR, A.TYPE_ID , A.ACTIVE)
  VALUES(B.PARID , B.HR, B.TYPE_ID , B.ACTIVE )
```

`PARID` и `TYPE_ID` не следует обновлять, потому что они используются в выражении связывания.

И подзапрос в USING - не нужен.